# How do I create a nested form that has a list of fields whose length is dependent on the count of another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

My application has customers and items. Items can have different prices for different customers. So, I have a `prices` table which references both the `customers` and `items` tables.

When creating a new item, I want the user to be able to also set each price individually for every single customer on the same form. So, on that item form, if there are 3 customers, I should see 3 names with a price field next to each one.

The problem is, those price records don't really exist yet and I can't figure out how to build that list and render it properly.

How can I build this form?

Below is what I've got so far (distilled as much as possible).

**[UPDATE]** - I've figured out how to get all the fields rendered in the view. However, the IDs for each generated price field wind up being the same, which, I think, screws up the JSON that's sent (only one price is received even if there is more than one price field on the form). Based on the docs, I think I should be able to include the array (`@item.prices`) in the fields_for, instead of having the `@items.prices.each` but that throws a 'undefined method error' for price_in_cents.

**Customer Model:**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_many :items, through: :prices
end
```

**Item Model:**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_many :customers, through: :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices 
end
```

**Price Model:**

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

**New Item Action:**

```
def new
    @item = Item.new
    @customers = Customer.all

    @customers.each do |cust|
        @item.prices.build
        # somehow need to also make all these new items have the correct customer IDs
    end
end
```

**Current New Item View: [UPDATED]**

```
<%= form_for :item, url: items_path do |f| %>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :name, 'Item Name' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', :autofocus => true %>
    </p>

    <% @item.prices.each do |item| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :prices, item do |p| %>
            <p>
                <%= p.label :price_in_cents, 'Price' %><br />
                <%= p.text_field :price_in_cents, class: 'form-control' %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm a RoR newbie and I'm having a hard time picturing how this should be built. Any insights?

Comment: I guess this will help you http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Thanks, I was digging through those episodes, but it's still not clicking with me in my particular case. I updated my question to hopefully clarify what exactly I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the cocoon gem.  It will dynamically create the amount of forms needed when the page is called.

Comment: Oh, interesting, thanks! I might try this out, however, I'd still like to understand how to accomplish this without a plugin.